# Number class swift

Tags: swift, casting

Is there a way to easily determine whether a value is a number? I was looking through the swift standard lib and couldn't seem to come to any conclusion. Something like so:

```
    var val: Any = ...
    if let number = val as? Number {
        //do something
    }
```

I don't really need to cast it just figure out whether or not it's a number. Rather than doing a bunch of Int,Double,etc checks.

Comment: Are you really not able to use the type system to help you out here?  Maybe your method should be parametrized by the only kind of data you're willing to take (numbers).  For example, try something like `func foo<T : IntegerArithmeticType>(val : T) { ... }`

Comment: Heck, you could even fake it yourself if you knew exactly what you wanted.  Make some kind of `NumericType` protocol and have empty extensions for all the types you can take.

Comment: Number is not a type until you define it.

Comment: I would really just prefer some pattern matching to determine if it's a Number. I understand i could create a class, just seems like something that should be in the standard lib.

Answer (score 2):

Given a variable of `Any` type, you can check if it's a number using a function like this:

```
func isNumber(value: Any) -> Bool {
    return (value is Int) || (value is UInt) || (value is Float) || (value is Double)
}
```

Interesting case, if the variable is of `AnyObject` type, any of these:

```
value is Int
value is UInt
value is Float
value is Double
value is Bool
```

will return `true` for all these data types:

- `Int`
- `UInt`
- `Float`
- `Double`
- `Bool`

so for example:

```
let x: AnyObject = false
x is Int // <== evaluates to true
x is Float // <== evaluates to true
```

Comment: Yeah I was trying to not do this. But thanks for the feedback. I was looking for something more for like an encapsulated number class. Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659311/how-can-i-check-an-object-to-see-its-type-and-return-a-casted-object